# Use Array.map() to render dynamic array but only for selected values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a commonly usable Table. In my table I need to show some selected values only from my data array. And the array object keys could be change. And my array contains a lot properties. I don't need to show them all in the table. Ex. IDs, Booleans.

Array:

```
const tableData =[{
  city: "New york"
  departmentId: "3"
  email: "email@gmail.com"
  fullName: "John Wick"
  gender: "male"
  hireDate: "2020-09-25T12:14:00.000Z"
  id: 2
  isPermanent: false
  mobileNumber: "0774695365"
  selectBoxTitle: "Accounting"
}]


const [records, setRecords] = useState(tableService.getAllTableData)
const [filterFn, setFilterFn] = useState({ fn: items => { return items; } })
```

And the table renders like this

```
<TableBody>
    recordsAfterPagingAndSorting().map(record => (
       <TableRow key={record.id}>
        <TableCell className="searchCell-body" size='small'>{record.fullName}</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="searchCell-body" size='small'>{record.email}</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="searchCell-body" size='small'>{record.mobileNumber}</TableCell>
        <TableCell size='small'>{record.selectBoxTitle}</TableCell>
        <TableCell size='small'>

            {figureActionButtons.viewMoreDetailsButton == true ?
                <Controls.ActionButton
                    color="primary"
                    tooltipText="View"
                    onClick={() => openInMoreDetailsPopup(record)}
                >
                    <SearchIcon fontSize="small" />
                </Controls.ActionButton> : null
            }
        </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
    ))
</TableBody>
```

`recordsAfterPagingAndSorting()` returns above array of objects.

```
const recordsAfterPagingAndSorting = () => {
    return stableSort(filterFn.fn(records), getComparator(order, orderBy)).slice(page * rowsPerPage, (page + 1) * rowsPerPage)
}
```

This Object can be changed. So I can not render `{record.fullName}` values like this. *fullName* can be come like *firstName, lastName*

And I need a way to define which values should be shown in the table. Define some ware and pass down to this .map() method.
I'm thinking of like `const tableBody = {columnOne: 'fullName', columnTwo: 'email', columnThree: 'city'}`

*I tried this but didn't worked*

```
<TableCell className="searchCell-body" size='small'>{recordsAfterPagingAndSorting()[record]}</TableCell>
```

Appreciate your help
Thank you.

Comment: Your array as posted has only one object in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do have an inner map method which enumerates the fields that you want displayed.

See example below:

```js
const tableData = [{
  city: "New york",
  departmentId: "3",
  email: "email@gmail.com",
  fullName: "John Wick",
  gender: "male",
  hireDate: "2020-09-25T12:14:00.000Z",
  id: 2,
  isPermanent: false,
  mobileNumber: "0774695365",
  selectBoxTitle: "Accounting",
}];

function MyComponent({records, fields}) {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          { fields.map(field => (
            <th key={field}>{field}</th>
          )) }
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        { records.map(record => (
          <tr key={record.id}>
            { fields.map(field => (
              <td key={field}>{record[field]}</td>
            )) }
          </tr>
        )) }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent records={tableData} fields={['email', 'fullName']}/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```